# Sed on a specific format 'newik'

Tags: bash, sed

I need some help to deal with a special format and apply a sed into it;

The format I'm talking about is such as :

```
((scaffold_123_150948-152847_+__Ra_raccoon:19.19959,chrm_189_150948-152847_+__Ra_bear:6.80041):0.84600,((chrm_143_150948-152847_+__sea_lion:11.99700, chrm_121_150948-152847_+__Ra_seal:12.00300):7.52973,((scaff14344788_150948-152847_+__Ra_monkey:100.85930,chrm_23_150948-152847_+__Ra_cat:47.14069):20.59201, scaff145788_150948-152847_+__Ra_weasel:18.87953):2.09460):3.87382,chrm_145_150948-152847_+__Ra_dog:25.46154);
```

Its a a newik format, in mathematics, Newick tree format is a way of representing graph-theoretical trees with edge lengths using parentheses and commas.

here we have `8 species_names`: (nodes names):

```
scaffold_123_150948-152847_+__Ra_raccoon
chrm_189_150948-152847_+__Ra_bear
chrm_143_150948-152847_+__sea_lion
chrm_121_150948-152847_+__Ra_seal
scaff14344788_150948-152847_+__Ra_monkey
chrm_23_150948-152847_+__Ra_cat
scaff145788_150948-152847_+__Ra_weasel
chrm_145_150948-152847_+__Ra_dog
```

and the idea is to transform them into the newik format into:

```
Ra_raccoon
Ra_bear
sea_lion
Ra_seal
Ra_monkey
Ra_cat
Ra_weasel
Ra_dog
```

and get :

```
((Ra_raccoon:19.19959,Ra_bear:6.80041):0.84600,((sea_lion:11.99700, Ra_seal:12.00300):7.52973,((Ra_monkey:100.85930,Ra_cat:47.14069):20.59201, Ra_weasel:18.87953):2.09460):3.87382,Ra_dog:25.46154);
```

I know that the command : `sed -i 's/^.*__/>/'` can do it if I take independently all nodes names but here in the newik format it is little bit complicated..

Does anyone have an idea? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jens I do not understrand, I put them into the input. These numbers do not have any importance, but I need to keep them in the output.

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to remove all part between `scaf` and `__` AND `chrm` and `__`no ?

Comment: it does not work @oguzismail ...

Comment: `sed` is very likely the wrong tool to parse nested expressions. Try a dedicated tool https://pypi.org/project/newick/ or see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891041/java-library-or-code-to-parse-newick-format or here https://gist.github.com/grondilu/4231207

Comment: Ok I found a way using ete3 from python thank you.